# VS Code Link Folder With Compiler Files to Editor

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-code

I have a C++ compiler located in a folder on my Desktop, and I have it set up so that I can run C++ through powershell, using the command:

./cl.exe (File Directory)(.cpp file)

I was hoping to access this compiler in Visual Studio Code so that when I press the run button, it will execute the .cpp file (I have the CodeRunner extension installed). The error message I get any time I try running is that g++ is not installed (A separate compiler), but I cannot install new components as I do not have administrator privileges. I tried creating a tasks.json file to change the command that the editor uses to try and run C++, but to no avail.

The end goal of my "setup" was to use a universal editor on both my mac and windows machine, and use git to work on my projects on both. I know that I could just use Notepad and the command line, but I was hoping to retain the nice features that I am accustomed to in VS Code.